# JavaScript - How to take a picture in webcam with EXIF data?

Tags: javascript, jpeg, webcam, exif

I am currently using webcam (not native camera) on a web page to take a photo on users' mobile phone. Like this:

```
var video: HTMLVideoElement;
...
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
var jpegData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', compression);
```

In such a way, I can now successfully generate a JPEG image data from web camera, and display it on the web page.

However, I found that the EXIF data is missing.
according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage):

> Canvas.drawImage() **will ignore all EXIF metadata in images,
>   including the Orientation.** This behavior is especially troublesome
>   on iOS devices. You should detect the Orientation yourself and use
>   rotate() to make it right.

I would love the JPEG image contain the EXIF GPS data. Is there a simple way to include camera EXIF data during the process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on Pixel 3 - it works. Please note - sometimes it does not work with some desktop web-cameras. you will need [exif-js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) to get the `EXIF` object from example.

```
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video : true });
  const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
  let imageCapture = new ImageCapture(track);
  imageCapture.takePhoto().then((blob) => {
      const newFile = new File([blob], "MyJPEG.jpg", { type: "image/jpeg" });
      EXIF.getData(newFile, function () {
          const make = EXIF.getAllTags(newFile);
          console.log("All data", make);
     });
  });
```

[image: Please check the image with EXIF data]

Comment: Hi jsDev, where do you get `EXIF` object from? It does not seem to be native

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius Hi, yes it is a part of **exif-js**

[link](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js)

Comment: [ImageCapture](https://caniuse.com/?search=ImageCapture) doesn't work with firefox and safari browser

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately there's no way to extract exif from canvas.

Although, if you have access to jpeg, you can extract exif from that. For that I'd recommend [exifr](https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr) instead of widely popular exif-js because exif-js has been unmaintained for two years and still has breaking bugs in it (n is undefined).

With exifr you can either parse everything

```js
exifr.parse('./myimage.jpg').then(output => {
  console.log('Camera:', output.Make, output.Model))
})
```

or just a few tags

```js
let output = await exifr.parse(file, ['ISO', 'Orientation', 'LensModel'])
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, according to what I found so far, there is no way to include exif data during canvas context drawing.

Second, there is a way to work around, which is to extract the exif data from the original JPEG file, then after canvas context drawing, put the extracted exif data back into the newly drawn JPEG file.

It's messy and a little hacky, but for now this is the work around. 
Thanks!